# Flutter firebase: Get document list

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get a list of document from the database in a subCollection. I'm not trying to get the of the subcollection CollectionB1 from from only one user, but from all users. But for some reason, I can't get it.

I've however been able to get the total docs in the subCollection but I can't get the data.

[image: Collection]

I got the total docs from the subCollection using the code bellow:

```
Stream<int> allAdsList() async* {
    var snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collectionGroup("CollectionB1")
        .get();
    yield snapshot.docs.length;
  }
```

I want to get all the data from all the subCollection `CollectionB1`  in a list. Here I'm not looking for data from a specific doc. But from all the docs.

I tried the following codes but non of them worked

First code:

```
StreamBuilder(stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("CollectionB1")
      .snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return const CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return ListView.builder(
            primary: true,
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              final info = snapshot.data!.docs[index];                                
              return Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  title:
                      Text(info.get("field"))
                ),
              );
            },
          );
    }
    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Text("Error");
    } else {
      return Center(
        child: Text("No data"),
      );
    }
  },
)
```

Code 2

```
StreamBuilder(stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("UserCollection")
      .doc()
      .collection("CollectionB")
      .doc()
      .collection("CollectionB1")
      .snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return const CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return ListView.builder(
            primary: true,
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              final info = snapshot.data!.docs[index];                                
              return Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  title:
                      Text(info.get("field"))
                ),
              );
            },
          );
    }
    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Text("Error");
    } else {
      return Center(
        child: Text("No data"),
      );
    }
  },
)
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the documents from all collections with the name `CollectionB1`, you need to call the `collectionGroup()` method (just like in your first code snippets). The other two code snippets call `collection()`, which will only get the documents from a top-level collection named `CollectionB1` (which probably doesn't exist).

So:

```
StreamBuilder(stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collectionGroup("CollectionB1") // 
      .snapshots(),
```

Comment: Sorry! I wanted to write 'collectionGroup' but I wrote collection. And yes, even with that I couldn't get the data

Comment: If your `allAdsList` works, I don't see why reading the same info in a `StreamBuilder` wouldn't work. I recommend setting a breakpoint on the first line in the `builder`, running in the debugger, and seeing whether it reaches there. If so, check the value of each variable on each line from there on - to find waht is goign wrong.